# Facing Gulp issuue while running the application

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to run one application included with gulp. After running "npm run gulp" this command
getting the below error.

```
> hcm-modern@1.1.0 gulp F:\Users\GIT\HCM_Backend\hcm-modern-data-layer
```

> gulp build

```
[02:25:01] Using gulpfile F:\Users\GIT\HCM_Backend\hcm-modern-data-layer\gulpfile.js
[02:25:01] Starting 'clean'...
Deleted typescript build
[02:25:01] Finished 'clean' after 60 ms
[02:25:01] Starting 'compile'...
[02:25:12] 'compile' errored after 11 s
[02:25:12] Error: Command failed: "F:/Users/GIT/HCM_Backend/hcm-modern-data-layer/node_modules/.bin/tsc"
at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:760:11)
at Object.execSync (child_process.js:833:15)
at Gulp.<anonymous> (F:\Users\GIT\HCM_Backend\hcm-modern-data-layer\gulpfile.js:45:16)
at module.exports (F:\Users\GIT\HCM_Backend\hcm-modern-data-layer\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:34:7)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (F:\Users\GIT\HCM_Backend\hcm-modern-data-layer\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:273:3)
at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (F:\Users\GIT\HCM_Backend\hcm-modern-data-layer\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:214:10)
at F:\Users\GIT\HCM_Backend\hcm-modern-data-layer\node_modules\orchestrator\index.js:279:18
at finish (F:\Users\GIT\HCM_Backend\hcm-modern-data-layer\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:21:8)
at eos.error (F:\Users\GIT\HCM_Backend\hcm-modern-data-layer\node_modules\orchestrator\lib\runTask.js:43:4)
```

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hcm-modern@1.1.0 gulp: `gulp build`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!`enter code here`
npm ERR! Failed at the hcm-modern@1.1.0 gulp script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR! C:\Users\503268772\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2021-09-21T06_25_12_502Z-debug.log